# Deploy Spring Boot war into Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, spring-boot

I have a `Jenkins` job for deploy Spring-Boot war.

When I launch my job I have this error:

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.5:war (default-war) @ rest-api ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [rest-api] in [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/BOAOBJ/workspace/target/rest-api-1.0.0]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [459 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/BOAOBJ/workspace/target/rest-api-1.0.0.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.RC1:repackage (default) @ rest-api ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.040 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-22T14:04:30+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.RC1:repackage (default) on project rest-api: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.RC1:repackage failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

***Pom.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.Lyreco.lab</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RC1</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <springfox-version>2.2.2</springfox-version>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>0.19.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>hal-browser</artifactId>
            <version>9f96c74</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.springsource.milestone</id>
            <name>SpringSource Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repository.springsource.milestone</id>
            <name>SpringSource Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Why ?

Comment: can you share your pom.xml?

Comment: @aksappy i share my `pom.xml`

Comment: Can you add <start-class><PACKAGENAME.CLASSNAME></start-class> in the properties section in your pom.xml and try again.

Comment: Just an observation, the version of Spring BOOT being used is a Release candidate of a version which is old. Latest GA version is 1.3.3

Answer (score 3):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.RC1:repackage (default) on project rest-api: 
Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.RC1:repackage failed: **Unable to find main class** -> [Help 1]
```

The spring-boot-maven-plugin allows you to package executable jar or war archives and run an application(automatically). So, you will need specify the Main class for your application.
See [guideline](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-launcher-manifest) here.

So, in short, you can add main class to your Manifest by:

1. Add directly to Manifest.MF
2. Specify [Optional Parameters](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging-optional-params) for spring-boot-maven-plugin in your pom.xml. Below is example:

   ```
   <plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <configuration>
       <mainClass>com.test.Application</mainClass>

   </configuration>
   <executions>
   <execution>
       <goals>
           <goal>repackage</goal>
       </goals>
   </execution>
   ```